# Split function not working under jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating raplet under which i have to split a string having following format `https://abc.com/mail/?hl=en&shva=3#inbox/123sdsdsdff` so that i get the `123sdsdsdff`. If i use the normal javascript function i am getting the correct string. Code is as below:

```
var url= 'https://abc.com/mail/?hl=en&shva=3#inbox/123sdsdsdff';

var splitlocation=url.split('#');
var newsplit=splitlocation[1].split('/');
alert(newsplit[1]);
```

If i copy the above code and insert in the below mentioned code its not working. I tried to escape the # character but still no success.

Raplet code is as below (Jquery):

```
$parameters['js'] = "$('div.info').hide(); $('p.head').click(function(){ $(this).next('div.info').slideToggle(600);});var url= 'https://abc.com/mail/?hl=en&shva=3#inbox/123sdsdsdff';var splitlocation=url.split('#');var newsplit=splitlocation[1].split('/');alert(newsplit[1]);$('#url').val(top.location);$('#savenote').click(function(){
$.getJSON('http://localhost/ajax.php?note='+$('#note').val()+'&url='+$('#url').val()+'&callback=?',
    function(data){ alert(data.success);});})";
```

I am confused where i am getting this wrong.

Comment: You're never calling `split` in your second code snippet. Copy & paste error?

Comment: thanks crowder for replying. i have already mentioned that Raplet code is as below (jquery version without split function):I have edited my question now i have added the split part also.

Answer (score 0):

And what do you do with this code than? 
Does it work(whole code, not only split-part) if you run it directly in a browser? 
Have you tried to assign to `$parameters['js']` only split-part(without $.getJSON) of the script? 
Are you using debugger(console)? Are there errors in it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the string that was being split. I have used `encodeURIComponent` function and it worked well.